# Get all parents of multiple objects in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, mysql-5.7

for an mass edit function I need to load the parents of multiple objects.
Doing this with single querys would kill the db. I'm using MySQL 5.7 My table is build like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text,
  `parentid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

INSERT INTO testtable(`id`, `content`, `parentid`)
    VALUES(1, 'parentA1', 0),(5, 'parentA2', 1),(3, 'childA', 2),
    (4, 'parentB', 0),(5, 'childB', 4);
```

For single object querys I use this statement to get all parents:

```
SELECT t.id, t.content, @pid := t.parentid AS parentid
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 order by id DESC) t
JOIN (SELECT @pid := 3) tmp
WHERE t.id = @pid
```

But I have absolutly no clue how this could work for multiple object at once without using union.

My whised ouput should look like this:

```
id | content | parentid | searchingChildID
1  | parentA1| 0        | 3
2  | parentA2| 1        | 3
3  | childA  | 2        | 3
4  | parentB | 0        | 5
5  | childB  | 4        | 5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Provide complete table script (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and show desired output for provided data strictly.

Comment: I don't understand how `searchingChildID` is determined.  Can you bertter explain?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is a typical use case for a recursive query. Say you want all parents of objects 3 and 4, you can do:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.id as originalid, t.* from table1 where id in (3, 4)
    union all
    select c.originalid, t.*
    from cte c
    inner join table1 t on t.id = c.parentid
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

> for an mass edit function I need to load the parents of multiple objects.

For this operation, I would expect:

```
id | content | parentid | ultimateparent
1  | parentA1| 0        | 0
2  | parentA2| 1        | 0
3  | childA  | 2        | 0
4  | parentB | 0        | 0
5  | childB  | 4        | 0
```

Because `0` is the ultimate parent of all the rows.  If you know the maximum depth, you can use `left join`s in pre-8 versions of MySQL:

```
select  t1.*, coalesce(t3.parentid, t2.parentid, t1.parentid) as ultimateparent
from testtable t1 left join
     testtable t2
     on t2.id = t1.parentid left join
     testtable t3
     on t3.id = t2.parentid
```

You can trivially extend this with more `left join`s to handle deeper levels of parentage.

If `0` really means "no parent" (which is an odd choice when `NULL` is available) then you would seem to want:

```
id | content | parentid | ultimateparent
1  | parentA1| 0        | 1
2  | parentA2| 1        | 1
3  | childA  | 2        | 1
4  | parentB | 0        | 4
5  | childB  | 4        | 4
```

Then you can actually just tweak the above query to:

```
select  t1.*, coalesce(t3.id, t2.id, t1.id) as ultimateparent
from testtable t1 left join
     testtable t2
     on t2.id = t1.parentid left join
     testtable t3
     on t3.id = t2.parentid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=52a95753382ddbc4d16eab770f6dbe45) is a db<>fiddle.

You can get the maximum child for each parent as well (although that seems quite arbitrary).  In pre-8.0 versions of MySQL, variables are the simplest approach:

```
select t1.*, 
       (@max_child := if(@up = ultimateparent, @max_child,
                         if(@up := ultimateparent, id, id)
                        )
       ) as max_childid
from (select  t1.*, coalesce(t3.id, t2.id, t1.id) as ultimateparent
      from testtable t1 left join
           testtable t2
           on t2.id = t1.parentid left join
           testtable t3
           on t3.id = t2.parentid
      order by ultimateparent, id desc
     ) t1 cross join
     (select @up := -1, @max_child := -1) params;
```